# Invoke-WmiMethod -ArgumentList not accepting variables?

Tags: powershell, scripting, configurationmanager, sccm

So I am very new to Powershell and I am almost certain that what I am doing is not the most efficient way of going about it. But I really want to understand why what I am doing is not working.

I am trying to trigger Configuration Manager client actions using Powershell by running the following code:

```
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
    Invoke-WmiMethod -Namespace "Root\CCM" -Class SMS_Client -Name 
    TriggerSchedule -ArgumentList "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000042}"
    }
```

This runs fine. But I wanted to be able to call a variable or something where all of those long codes are instead of having to put those in each time I want to change the client action. So here is where I started playing around and was unable to get anything to work.

```
    $ApplicationDeployment = '"{00000000-0000-0000-0000000000000042}"'

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
    Invoke-WmiMethod -Namespace "Root\CCM" -Class SMS_Client -Name 
    TriggerSchedule -ArgumentList $ApplicationDeployment
    }
```

This gives me an error. I also tried the following:

```
    $hash = @{"ApplicationDeployment" = "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000042}"}

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
    Invoke-WmiMethod -Namespace "Root\CCM" -Class SMS_Client -Name 
    TriggerSchedule -ArgumentList $hash.'ApplicationDeployment'
    }
```

and finally

```
    $Object = @{ApplicationDeployment = '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000042}'}

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
    Invoke-WmiMethod -Namespace "Root\CCM" -Class SMS_Client -Name 
    TriggerSchedule -ArgumentList $Object.ApplicationDeployment
    }
```

I have also tried

```
   $($ApplicationDeployment).ArgumentList
```

But this gives the same error as everything else.

I would really appreciate an explanation as to why this isn't working... Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that remote machine doesn't have your variable initialized locally. You need to pass it to remote machine when executing script.
To do this, replace $Object.ApplicationDeployment with $Using:Object.ApplicationDeployment as in code below:

```
$Object = @{ApplicationDeployment = '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000042}'}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
    Invoke-WmiMethod -Namespace "Root\CCM" -Class SMS_Client -Name TriggerSchedule -ArgumentList $Using:Object.ApplicationDeployment
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.